# EEEPC 900 running Jaunty not automounting sd card after upgrade to kernel 2.6.28-15

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, kernel, sd-card

I recently used the Ubuntu update manager to upgrade the kernel on my netboook to 2.6.28-15.  The problem is that the new kernel no longer auto-mounts my SD card, which happens to contain my /home directory.  The funny thing is, if I use the "recovery mode" grub option, and then "resume normal" the card gets mounted.  How do I ensure my sd card is mounted on boot?

Answer (score 0):

See [fstab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab).

Comment: I'll double check fstab, I didn't realize that updating the kernel would overwrite it.  The SD Card was mounting fine before the upgrade.

Comment: Not an fstab problem.  I've double check it, and fstab is fine.

Comment: whats you're fstab entry for the sd card?